# Is there anyway to add multiple ssh keys for one user in JFrog Artifactory?

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface, artifactory

Is there anyway to add multiple ssh keys for one user in JFrog Artifactory? I am administrating multiple servers and want to use Artifactory CLI with ssh-key to access artifacts in the repository.

EDIT: I'm using Artifactory to publish multiple instance of one application into different servers. On each server there exists some users and some running applications where each user has access to deploy newer versions of some of those applications. The problem is that I do not want to share my public-private key for my user on different servers (Of course I'm not a security expert and don't really know whether this is a right decision or not :) )

Comment: Artifactory currently supports a single SSH key per user. If you can add more information about your need I might be able to provide a better answer

Comment: I added more description on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the use case described would be creating Artifactory [user accounts](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Users) for all the users who needs to deploy. Then you can grant the users deployment [permissions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions) for the applications they are working on.
For each of these users you can configure its own SSH key, so you will not need to share your own key.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is with a single user on different servers. By sharing my public-private key pair, I meant using one key pair for my own user on different servers, not for different users on one server :)